# How to builf models.config for tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to host multiple models on tensorflow serving .
Tensorflow serving documents states that : Create a file containing an ASCII ModelServerConfig protocol buffer.
But I am not able to build this models.config .
Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_config) you are referring to, you need to create a plaintext file in the Google [ProtoBuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en) structure. Then, you save this file, and you pass a `model_config_file` flag to the model server executable with the path to the file you have just created. If you are running docker, there is a section in GtHub [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/docker.md#passing-additional-arguments) dedicated to that.

Comment: I used the same thing, but it is giving me below error :  `F tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:97] Non-OK-status: ParseProtoTextFile(file, &proto) status: Not found: /opt/script/TFServingModelFactory/models.config; No such file or directory`   the file is there in the specified path